# Timesheet hours difference in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string '08:30-16:30' describing working hours.
I also have the time someone has worked, in HH:mm format,eg.09:15

What is the easiest-fastest way to convert them in dates and find the difference in HH:mm format ?
Should i use Moment.js?
Also,i need the difference in minutes or seconds so that i can do comparisons with that.

I would be grateful if you could give me some examples.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you mean by the difference. Do you have a sample input and output?

Comment: Sorry,first i need the difference from "08:30-16:30",let's say diff1 (in any format you prefer).
And then i need the fifference between diff1 and "09:15"(probably in the same format as diff1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding the difference between the working hours, you could make use of MomentJS.

Example:

```
var working_hours = '08:30-16:30';
var hours_arr = working_hours.split('-'); // Gives an array with ['08:30', '16:30']

var start = moment(hours_arr[0], "HH:mm");
var end = moment(hours_arr[1], "HH:mm");

var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));

var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes());
```

The `minutes` variable would contain the difference in minutes.